# Is there any way to make F# discriminated unions work in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, f#

I am experimenting with F# in Unity. I use compiled F# library and FSharp.Core.dll copied to Assets in Unity. Simple scripts work but when I add discriminated union type like

```
type A = 
    | AInt of int 
    | AString of string
```

then I get this error in Unity: **"Unable to load attribute info on method fs.A:.ctor (). Are you missing a reference?"**.
What can be wrong and is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Looks like Unity expects a parameterless constructor on that type, but it doesn't have one, because from .NET POV it's an abstract base type.

Comment: I don't know much about F# but ensure the resulting binary is compatible with .NET Framework 4.x in order to be useful to Unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you are using F# **4.1** - **4.8** in order to be compatible with Unity.  **F# 5** and **6** are **incompatible** in exactly the same way as a C# project targeting *beyond* **.NET Standard 2.1**.

### Tell me more

- *[.NET profile support](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html)*
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_(programming_language)
- [.NET Standard Versions](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/v2.1.0/docs/versions.md)

Comment: Thanks. It works with net framework 4.7.2 (previously was net 6.0). Btw, I see (first link in your post) unity supports net standard 2.1 and net 6.0 has an implementation of net standard 2.1, so why it is not working? Am I missing smth?

Comment: @XaLVa _"Btw, I see (first link in your post) unity supports net standard 2.1 and net 6.0 has an **implementation of net standard 2.1**, so why it is not working?"_ - you are confusing concepts.  .NET Standard is best thought of as a _**baseline**_ of .NET platforms that are compliant for a given .NET Standard version rather than an _actual thing to compile against._ e.g. a .NET Core 3.0 class library is also known as a **.NET Standard 2.1** compliant library.  Similarly a .NET Framework 4.6.11 class library and .NET Core 2.0 library are compliant against **.NET Standard 2.0**....

Comment: **...however,** .NET Standard stopped at version **2.1** and there are **no** plans for .NET Standard 3.x/4.x/5.x etc.  .NET 6 are waaay beyond .NET Core 3.0 let alone anything defined in .NET Standard land.   
 Check out this table, I found it very helpful: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/v2.1.0/docs/versions.md